# Angular Material Table: Search a value based on two database columns but single UI columns

Tags: angular, filter, angular-material, angular8, mat-table

I am trying to add a filter on my name column which consists of **firstname + lastname** keys. The filter works fine till I search either with the first name or with the last name. But when I search with the full name no - no result comes up.

For example if a column has a value - "Charlie Opas"

searching **charlie** yields results, searching **opas** yields results but searching **charlie opas** doesn't give anything. below is my code.

component.ts

```
  displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'firstName',
    'org.name',
    'role.name',
    'email',
    'status.name',
    'action',
  ];

public doFilter = (value: string) => {
    this.dataSource.filter = value.trim().toLocaleLowerCase();
  }
```

component.html

```
 <input matInput type="text" (keyup)="doFilter($event.target.value)"  name="username"/>

 <ng-container matColumnDef="firstName">
          <th scope="col" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
            User Name
          </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.firstName +' '+ element.lastName}}</td>
        </ng-container>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you create stackblitz to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Will a solution using custom Angular pipe, be of any help??